# Angular - Modify the data based on another service and return an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have one service that returns a list of vehicles. I need to get the driver for each vehicle and set it for the bus.
So far, I have implemented it in such a way:

```js
    return this.getVehicles().pipe(
      // Set the driver
      map((res) => {
        res.items = res.items.map((vehicle) => {
          if (vehicle.driver_id !== "") {
            this.driverSvc.get(vehicle.driver_id).subscribe((data) => {
              vehicle.driver = data;
            })
          }
          return vehicle;
        })
        return res;
      }),
      map((res) => {
        // This map needs to have the driver!
        console.log(vehicle.driver) // Undefined in all cases, where it should be set for one of the entries
      })
```

I know the `console.log(vehicle.driver)` logs `undefined` because of the `subscribe`. Is there any other way to modify my response based on the response from another service?

Comment: you need to use the `switchMap` operator to combine two observables to a observable chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i already mentioned you need to use the `switchMap` operator to combine the two observables to a chain. The following example could maybe work for you:

```js
        return this.getVehicles.pipe(
            // load the driver
            switchMap((response) =>
                zip(
                    ...response.map((vehicle) =>
                        this.driverSvc.get(vehicle.driver_id).pipe(map((driver) => {
                            vehicle.driver = driver;
                            return vehicle;
                        })),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            map((responseWithDriver) => {
                // this map needs to have the driver!
                console.log(responseWithDriver);
            }),
        );
```

The `switchMap` let us use a new observable as return value and the `zip` operator let us combine multiple calls to one return value.

**UPDATE (with if)**
As you ask in the comments here is a version with the `if` statement:

```js
        return this.getVehicles.pipe(
            // load the driver
            switchMap((response) =>
                zip(
                    ...response.map((vehicle) => {
                        if (vehicle.driver_id === "") { // if no driver
                            return of(vehicle); // return observable from unedit data
                        }
                        // else return request with modified data
                        return this.driverSvc.get(vehicle.driver_id).pipe(map((driver) => {
                            vehicle.driver = driver;
                            return vehicle;
                        })),
                    }
                        
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            map((responseWithDriver) => {
                // this map needs to have the driver!
                console.log(responseWithDriver);
            }),
        );
```

The `of` operator is needed in this case because it generates a observable from our static vehicle and i think that `zip` just accepts observables.

Comment: I just wonder if it would make a difference if you used `forkJoin()` instead of `zip()`?

Comment: Btw: I think you forgot the `map`-operator in the following part of your code: `get(vehicle.driver_id).pipe((driver)`. And maybe the `map` at the end of your code should rather be a `tap`?

Comment: yea you are right, i muss the `map` in the driver get pipe. with `forkJoin` i am not shure if this would be the same because i think that forkjoin only emits if the observables completes. but you can try and look at the results

Comment: Assuming that `this.driverSvc.get()` merely triggers a http-request, I guess that `forkJoin` would be equivalent for our use case. Http-requests complete after their first emission and if one of the requests fails to complete, neither `zip` nor `forkJoin` would produce any output. As far as I understand `zip` only completes if all observables returned at least one value + one observable was completed.

Comment: My last question: `...response.map((vehicle) =>` means that you clone the resulting observable-array. I don't yet understand why this is necessary here. Anyway, I now gave you an upvote because your solution is basically the way to go ;-).

Comment: @DerHerrGammler, thank you for your help! It seems to be working, but I can't find a place to put the if statement I had previously. I need to get the driver only if the driver_id is set. I tried with `if` and `iif` but I cannot place them anywhere :/ I'm really sorry if that's a silly question, but where I can put it? I'm really new to Angular and as of now, it really differs from my backend stuff :D

Comment: @xaos_xv i add an update to my answer with if. but you can also just return no driver from the server and you would probably also be fine with the result of the previous code

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go with the approach of returning null from the service if the ID is not set. Thank you once again!